# How to set up Time Capsule to takeover DHCP & NAT from your ISP Modem/Router

Tags: network, time-capsule

I would greatly appreciate anyone who is able to shed some light and assist me with setting up my network so that the DHCP and NAT on the network is handled solely by Time Capsule. This is so I can use BacktoMyMac...or AFP via an external network.

I have tried but failed miserably :( im so frustrated now !!! I’m grinding away at my teeth and soon it will be my gums

Ok..this is the scenario....

- I have an NBN Connection via VDSL2 100/40 Mbps which doesn’t require authentication PPPoE ; It uses DHCP
- I have an Apple Time Capsule Latest Generation
- I have a modem provided by the ISP MyRepublic .. It’s a [Technicolor 
  MediaAccess TG789MYRvac v2 HP]
- I have a need to access the Time Capsule whilst outside the LAN, I need remote access to the NAS.

I put the modem/router into Bridge mode so that it’s just functioning as a modem/switch. To do this I entered the modem interface and under DHCP clicked Bridge Mode.

I then connected a CAT 5/6 Ethernet cable to LAN port 1 on the modem and the other side connected to the Time Capsule Ethernet port on the bottom.

The modem restarted and as expected I could not access the modem interface anymore.

I logged into the Time Capsule and set it up as follows :

Internet Connection : Set to DHCP as the ISP assigns me a non-static Public IP

- IP Address (ISP DHCP Assigned)
- Subnet 255.255.0.0
- Router IP (LAN 192.168.1.1)

Router Mode : Set to DHCP and NAT since bridge mode on the Modem should have effectively disabled these features.

- DHCP range (Whatever IP range I choose from the 3 available options)
- Range Beginning : 2
- Range End : 253
- Reservations : None
- Lease : 24H
- Default Host : Not Set
- Enabled NAT-PMP

The settings were saved and I was able to access the internet via TimeCapsule and there was no Double NAT or Conflicts reported. However, access over the internet was intermittent for some reason and the upload speed was quite slow.

I don’t know why ... is there a problem with the hardware, me or both :(

I have previously set this up via the same Time Capsule and different modem and ISP and had no problems..so baffled